# Similar triangles in the complex plane and the determinant

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115872/condition-for-similar-triangles-in-complex-plane) earlier and it made me wonder if the converse of the statement is true. With the condition that for two triangles with the complex number vertices $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and $z_1', z_2', z_3'$, if $$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\z_1&z_2&z_3\\z_1'&z_2'&z_3'\end{vmatrix}=0$$
then are the two triangles similar?
It's fairly obvious to see that the sides of the triangles are proportionate using the same argument in the linked post, but I can't find a good way to demonstrate congruency.

Comment: The converse is true, and it follows from the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3116022/291201) under the linked question. The equality $\;\dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1} = \dfrac{z_3'-z_1'}{z_2'-z_1'}\;$ means you have two pairs of proportional sides with an equal angle between them, which is the SAS case of triangle similarity.

Comment: I understand how you can reach the equality when assuming similarity, but how are the two separate sides shown as proportional in that equality? And how exactly do you derive the angle? (eg. if it was to be shown explicitly they are similar as: A/B = A'/B', C/B = C'/B', and angle a = angle a')

Comment: You just equate the modulus and argument between the two sides. $\left|\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right|$ $= \frac{\,|z_3-z_1|\,}{\,|z_2-z_1|\,}$ is the ratio of the side lengths, and $\arg\left(\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right)$ $=\arg(z_3-z_1) - \arg(z_2-z_1)$ is the angle between them.